# comparing variation of a blended product from populations of different sizes (dilutions)

Tags: variance, standard-deviation

*Original question*: If population 1 consists of blended piles of size X_1 and population 2 consists of blended piles of size 4*X_1.  Should I expect the standard deviation of X_1 to be equal to 4*the standard deviation of X_2 ?  How do I otherwise compare the standard deviation of these two populations?

**Edit to reword the question (with different analogy).**

**Population 1**: Huge buckets of many different coloured balls (56 possible colours), each bucket of size X1

**Population 2**: Tiny buckets of the same coloured balls (again 56 possible colours), each bucket of size X2.  Because the balls are the same size / density, each bucket in this population has a much smaller quantity of balls than the buckets in population 1.

The balls have the same density and are not mixed well in either of the populations.

**Samples**

- I take n1 "handfuls" of coloured balls, each handful from a different bucket from population 1 and take a weighted measurement of some undefined attribute for each handful.  I repeat the process for population 2 and get n2 measurements.
- I was told that because population 1 buckets are larger I should expect less variation in the n1 measurements than in the n2 measurements.
- It has been suggested that I apply normalisation factors of
  1/sqrt(X1) and 1/sqrt(X2) to the standard deviations to make them comparable, however I cannot find any relevant theory or sources of information.

Comment: I don't think I understand quite what's being asked here. Can you explain in more detail what's going on?

Comment: @Glen_b: Yes, you are right, my original question was not very clear.  Please let me know if the edited question needs further clarification.